# Return TypeORM delete mutation

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I can't make a delete mutation an error occurs in function return.

If I run BairroDelete in GraphQL then an error occurs from Mutation in graphql.

Message:

> Field \ BairroDelete \ must not have a selection since type \" Boolean! \ Has no subfields.,

Code:

```
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Arg } from "type-graphql";
import { Bairro } from "../entities/Bairro";
import { status } from "../enumerador";

@Resolver(of => Bairro)
export class BairroResolver {
  @Query(returns => [Bairro])
  async Bairros() {
    return await Bairro.find();
  }

  @Mutation(() => Bairro)
  async BairroSave(
    @Arg("nome") nome : string
  ) 
  {
    const ativo = await status.Ativo;

    const bairro = await Bairro.create({
      nome,
      status: ativo
    }).save()

    return bairro;
  }

  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async BairroDelete(
    @Arg("id") id : string
  ) 
  {
    const sucesso = await Bairro.delete({ id });
    return sucesso;  // <<<<<< ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Field \ BairroDelete \ must not have a selection since type \" Boolean! \ Has no subfields.

You need to show us your graphql mutation document.

It looks like you're doing something like this:

```
mutation {
  BairroDelete(id: 123) {
    status
  }
}
```

Which is illegal, since `BairroDelete` returns boolean scalar, not object type that you can select fields from.

However, this is legal:

```
mutation {
  BairroDelete(id: 123)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sucesso` that you are returning from `Bairro.delete` is not a Boolean type, it is an object DeleteResult from TypeOrm that looks like this:

```
DeleteResult {
  raw: OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0
  },
  affected: 0
}
```

Firstly you have to define what is going to be the "success" for you delete operation because it may not affect any row at all. What is missing is this translation from the returned object from TypeOrm into what you are willing to respond to in your Graphql mutation. Delete is not like other operations, whereas most of the time you get the Entity instances back and just return it.